# Register "Author" attribute to specific taxonomy [Wordpress]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have custom taxonomy type called "Slider Locations". You can add locations.

I want users to be able to see and create new Slider Locations.
Also so that user see only own Slider Locations.

Slider Locations taxonomy is registered in theme's **functions.php**.

Would it be possible to add in functions or in Wordpress CORE's taxonomies something like this?

idea / sketch

```
If taxonomy has label "slider-locations" > do this
{
add attribute ( 'Author' );
}
// this is just a sketch idea
else
{
// do nothing
}
```

**note:** Author means also "user id". I would love to implement it so that taxonomy term acts like post / page. User can create new ones and see only own ones.

Comment: You could add metadata with author's user id to the taxonomy terms. Its not as straightforward as adding metadata to posts, but used in various places, so you should have no trouble finding examples.

Comment: Cool, I have found few articles about metadata for taxonomies. It might be the way. Now I just need to find somewhere how to exactly write code printing "author's user id" into taxonomy term (item) when it is created.

Comment: `wp_get_current_user()` should help you out there

Comment: Thanks man. You've got me on the road.

Comment: Okey, I am still kinda lost. I have found plugin "Taxonomy Metadata" which could do the job. Also the "Taxonomy Meta Script" which works for adding additional information to taxonomies. However I think my problem is slightly less complicated. I do not want to add custom fields. I just want to register who created the taxonomy term (user id). I have also found this topic [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8428/multiple-users-only-allow-them-to-manage-their-own-terms-for-custom-taxonomy-w](multi users taxonomy terms) which unfortunately doesn't work for me.

Comment: You'll have to keep this information of who created what taxonomy somewhere. If not metadata associated with the taxonomy, then where? I suppose you could keep it with the user ( user meta, wont be much easier ) or in an option ( doesn't scale well, wouldn't use this if you have a ton of users and taxonomy terms ).

Comment: I understand it. However, my lack of Wordpress PHP Functionality knowledge is standing between me and easy implementing of this feature. Would you mind to get in touch (contact)? Only if you want of course :].